# Powershell parameter condition

Tags: powershell, parameters

```
function test{
    [cmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Age, 
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Sex, 
        [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Location,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateSet("True","False")][string]$Favorite
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)[string]$FavoriteCar
    )

}
```

let's say first three parameters are required but not the 4th and 5th.  For $Favorite, I can only pass true or false but by default it would be $false but if I pass true, I want $favoriteCar to be set to $true.

Answer (score 1):

```
function test{
    [cmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'all')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Age, 
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Sex, 
        [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Location,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Extra',Mandatory=$true)][bool]$Favorite,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Extra',Mandatory=$true)][string]$FavoriteCar
    )


    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'extra')
    {
        if($Favorite)
        {
            Write-Host ('age:{0}, sex: {1}, location: {2}, favcar: {3}' -f $age ,$sex, $Location,$FavoriteCar)
        }
        else
        {
            'nothing'
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host ('age:{0}, sex: {1}, location: {2}' -f $age ,$sex, $Location)
    }

}
```

you dont need to do `[ValidateSet("True","False")][switch]` because `[switch]` always evaluates to a boolean.`true` if present, else`false`

If no default parameter set name is specified, PS would default to whichever ParameterSetName it finds on a parameter which in this case is `extra` and will prompt you for the favcar parameter which is mandatory. Of course there is no `all` parameterset specified but we set it so PS dosent attempt to run the `extra` ParameterSet by default.

**EDIT**

in the below command since parameters `$favorite\$favoritecar` are not used PS will not prompt you for any values.

```
test -Age 10 -Sex female -Location Moon
```

Output :

```
age:10, sex: female, location: Moon
```

the below will force PS to use the parameterset 'extra' and prompt you to enter a value for the parameter `$favoritecar` because it is mandatory in the parameterset 'extra'.

```
test -Age 10 -Sex female -Location Moon -favorite $true
```

the below will still prompt you for the `$favoritecar` parameter because it is mandatory however nothing will be processed because of the `if` condition in the code.

```
test -Age 10 -Sex female -Location Moon -Favorite $false -FavoriteCar Ferrari
```

Output :

```
nothing
```

Comment: Hi Kiran, sorry I wasn't probably clear on my question.  I need $Favorite to return either True or False. so.. if I do test -age 5 -sex m -location here -favorite true, I want $FavoriteCar to be set to "True" automatically.  if I pass false to $Favorite, $FavoriteCar don't need to be used

Comment: Hi Jay, i dont understand how would use the $favourite return value...can you edit you question and post where exactly you want to see $true returned?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Kiran. Just edited the question

Comment: I am not sure why you want to specifically pass a boolean to $favourite because if you set it to type `switch` and dont specify it as a function parameter then its value would be false. you can see that by setting a breakpoint in the function. However to do what you state is going to require Dynamic parameters (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2014/06/09/dynamic-validateset-in-a-dynamic-parameter/) . Maybe there is a better approach but this is what i could think of.

Comment: Hi Kiran, if I do test -age 5 -sex m -location usa -favorite,  can I have $favoritecar default to be "true"?

Comment: param(
            [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Age, 
            [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Sex, 
            [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Location,
            [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Extra')][switch]$Favorite ="true",
            [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Extra',Mandatory=$true)][string]$FavoriteCar="true"
        )  this doesn't seem to work